# oracle subquery not working

Tags: sql, oracle

trying to find out what I'm missing here. I have two tables, `resort` and `accommodations`. trying to get the most expensive cost per night tied to the resort that offers this option:

```
SELECT name,resort_id
  FROM resort
  WHERE resort_id IN ( SELECT MAX(cost_per_night)
                         FROM accommodations
                     );
```

the above returns blank columns.

Comment: both are tied with resort_id

Comment: SELECT cost_per_night,description
FROM accommodations
WHERE cost_per_night IN(
SELECT MAX(cost_per_night)

that gives me what I want but missing the resort that offers this which is in the resort table
FROM accommodations);

Comment: Would it make sense to perform a join? Something like SELECT name,distinct resort_id FROM resort r JOIN accommodations a ON a.resort_id = r.id ORDER BY cost_per_night DESC

Comment: not allowed to use join, only sub queries.

Comment: @user3015045 this smells like homework they should ask better questions and give better homework on schools now a days and should learn you how to optimize SQL qeuries (because BIG data is an trend now a days).. and an JOIN will scale beter on BIG data if the indexes are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could do something along these lines:

```
SELECT name, resort_id
  FROM resort
  WHERE resort_id IN ( SELECT resort_id
                         FROM accomodations
                         WHERE cost_per_night = ( SELECT MAX(cost_per_night)
                                                   FROM accommodations
                                                )
                     )
```

Your query was finding `resort_id` equal to a price rather than a `resort_id` equal to a `resort_id` with the maximum price. Also note that there could be multiple resorts with the same maximum price, hence the `IN`. Otherwise could do an order by desc with rownum = 1.

UPDATE: include price:

```
SELECT r.name, r.resort_id, a.cost_per_night
  FROM accomodations a
  JOIN resort r ON (a.resort_id = r.resort_id)
  WHERE a.cost_per_night = ( SELECT MAX(cost_per_night)
                               FROM accommodations
                           )
```

Comment: this gives me the correct resort name that has the highest price, but doesnt show the price...

Comment: Thanks Glenn, this works. I will try and figure out how to accomplish this without a JOIN.